# Magento 2 Bundle Product Add To Cart Like Simple Product

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, bundle

We have bundle products that are just groupings of simple products. I have disabled all options for the bundle products so that customers can't edit quantities etc. because I want them to act like simple products. For stock reasons, we need to use bundle products.

What I would like however is for the "ADD TO CART" Button to behave like a simple product and if it is clicked from say a "Category Page" It gets added directly to the cart. I.e. have the same functionality of simple products "add to cart" button from a "Category Page".

There are similar questions but so far I have not found a solution.

Current Code for the "Add To Cart Button" Is:

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
<button type="submit"
title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
class="action tocart primary">
<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try grouped products not bundle.

A grouped product consists of simple standalone products that are presented as a group. You can offer variations of a single product, or group them by season or theme. Presenting a grouped product can create an incentive for customers to purchase additional items. A grouped product provides an easy way to offer variations of a product, and list them all on the same page.

For example, you might sell open stock flatware, and list every type of utensil that is used in a formal place setting. Some might order multiple salad forks, fish forks, dinner forks, dinner knives, fish knives, butter knives, soup spoons, and dessert spoons. Other customers might order a simple fork, knife, and spoon. Customers can order as many of each item as they want.

Comment: There are various reasons to prefer bundles over grouped products. For example, you can't really configure the prices of grouped products well.